# Google Maps API V3 - adding variable to addListener(poly, 'click')

Tags: google-maps, event-listener, polyline

**SOLVED**

Already solved it, made a mistake. I thought you couldn't set a var to the poly object, but you can.

**QUESTION**

I'm trying to create a tool where users can create multiple polylines and save them into a database. When a users creates a line it is saved as a encoded string (encodePath) into a array. I also want users to be able to delete the lines by clicking on the line, this I did by using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function() {
  this.setMap(null);
  polylines[array_id] = ""; //how do i set the array_id to this eventlistener?
}
```

Now I also need to delete the encoded string from the array, my question here is: how do I add a variable (the array_id of the encoded string) to this eventlistener?

When i use the code as written above, it ofcourse gives the last array_id and not the array_id of the polyline.